# Calculated Columns with Conditions

Tags: 2013, list, javascript, calculated-column, conditional

I have found plenty of posts that mentioned how to add multiple conditions to calculated column but my formula is not working.  The action is pretty simple that is why I feel like silly that it has taken me forever to figure it out.  Here are the conditions.  If Column A is greater than 2,000 (text column) and Column B = Agreement (choice column) show "yes".  Here is the formula created.

```
 =IF(Column A)>2,000, IF(Column B)="Agreement"; Yes)
```

Can someone help me figure out what is wrong?

Comment: You should use Column A as a number column if you want to store the numbers only.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **VALUE** function to convert text to number.

> **VALUE** function Converts a text string that represents a number to a number.
>
> **Syntax**:
>
> **VALUE(text)**
>
> **text** is the text enclosed in quotation marks or a column reference containing the text you want to convert.

Use below formula(If your `Column` A field always going to have valid number stored in it):

```
=IF(VALUE([Column A])>2000,IF([Column B]="Agreement","Yes","No"),"No")
```

Else, use below formula in case you want handle the error condition when `Column A` field will not have valid number stored in it:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VALUE([Column A]))=TRUE,"No",IF(VALUE([Column A])>2000,IF([Column B]="Agreement","Yes","No"),"No"))
```

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(,) does not work in formula (I am not sure but it is based on something language on your site). So in that case use semicolon(;) instead of comma(,).
2. In `VALUE` function text parameter can be in any of the constant number, date, or time formats. If text is not in one of these formats, `VALUE` returns the `#VALUE!` or `#Name?` error value(to avoid this error, make sure you are entring valid number in Column A).

**References**:

1. [VALUE function in SharePoint](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/value-function-1fc46e51-4a25-4ba0-bce2-512dd5d4d872).

Comment: Hi, If this answer helps you then please upvote and [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) so that it will not be shown in Unanswered questions list.